# Need to authenticate before a web service call

Tags: restful-authentication

I am writing rest full web services for android and IOS app in Springs. I need to authenticate device and user before every service call. How can i do this? Is there any single process that can be used in every service? Is there any process of redirecting web service url to another service for authentication??

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Look into [HTTP Basic Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), [HTTP Digest Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication), and [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oauth) (which violates REST a little bit).